# Accepting answers during the private beta

Tags: discussion, questions

We're asking a lot of good questions, I think - and some of them already have what I would consider to be fantastic answers.

However, do we accept these answers, or wait for the public beta to give newcomers more questions to answer while leaving the possibility of being accepted open?

I don't think this should dictate any kind of policy on the matter, I'm just wondering what might be customary for a private beta.

Comment: If a question has an answer that normally would be accepted, what are the chances someone else would add a similar answer just for it to be accepted?  I feel like it would just get left as a question without a formally accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of the private beta is to jump-start the community. This includes posting content but it *also* includes **showing newcomers the desired and expected activity of the community.** First time users need to see how the site is used. They need to see all the features and functionality at work, organically.

So in this regard, use the site exactly like you would a live, public site. If you feel you have received the answer that is most helpful to you, accept it. Knowing that more people will read your question down the road, if you feel that you may receive a better answer, wait it out.

But don't hold back on those activities waiting for the public doors to open. **We want to portray how the site and the community should behave in actual use.**